# maven error in deploying jar file to remote repo

Tags: svn, maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I am using maven 2.2.1. I am issuing the following command to add a local jar to remote repo -

> `mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=/tmp/newUtil-2.1.0.0.jar -DgroupId=com.tareque.utils -DartifactId=newUtil -Dversion=2.1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=myrepo -Durl=svn:https://<my-repo-url>`

The `repositoryId` matches with the `id` in the `mirror` tag in the *settings.xml* file. The above commands gives the below error.

> [INFO] Error deploying artifact: Unsupported Protocol: 'svn': Cannot
>   find wagon which supports the requested protocol: svn
>
> Component descriptor cannot be found in the component repository:
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagonsvn.

This dependency is not present in my `pom.xml`, and  my project was built successfully. I am getting the above error only while deploying one of the jar created from other project locally to the remote repo.

How do I fix this?

#### Edit

Removed `svn` from the url, followed the [password ecnryption stpes here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html). Now I am getting this error

> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Error deploying artifact: Failed to transfer file:  http:// my-repo-url-with-complete-path-to-jar. Return code is: 409

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to use an `svn:` suffix at all - a Maven repository should have nothing to do with source control. Perhaps if you can explain what your remote repository is, we can help further.

Comment: That's what one of my colleague told to add as the remote repo is a subversion link. Also tried without `svn` prefix, but that gives me `Return code is: 401`. Are you aware of any `-f` switch to `maven deploy` that takes deploy.pom. I was advised that this is the proper way to add a jar in remote repo, but searching for this over the net doesn't yield any useful result.

Comment: If using the svn prefix actually returned a 401, it seems that it may indeed be a valid URL for your "subversion link" repo. But I have no idea what such a thing consists of.  Nonetheless, a 401 indicates that maven was able to attempt the deploy, and you simply didn't have valid credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `svn:` and add user/pw [as documented](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html). HTTP 401 means that you need to authenticate against the server.

Comment: I am not issuing the command from any  project direcoty. I am in a normal directory. Do we have to be in the project root dir? I had read [this maven doc](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html) which needs the parameters as given in my post.

Comment: @mtk, can be from any dir. For user/pw just edit `settings.xml` as explained in the doc I linked.

Comment: I did remove `svn:`, and later following the [password encryption steps here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html), I setup the config files. Now I am getting `Return code 409`.

Comment: @mtk, tried Google? HTTP 409 generally means "conflict". Did you re-deploy an existing artifact? You might also try `scm:svn:https:` but I doubt it helps...